# How to update an edge property by adding new value to existing one?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I want to upsert edge property to add new value to existing one (add number of user's sessions `n_sessions` after last update)

I've tried smt like this:

```
%%gremlin
g.V('index-1')
     .outE('route')
     .where(inV().hasId('index-2'))
     .fold()
     .coalesce(unfold(),
                V('index-1'')
                    .addE('route')
                    .property('max_time', 1687219210)
                    .to(V('index-2')))
     .filter(values('max_time').is(lt(1687219211)))
     .property('max_time', 1687219211)
     .sideEffect(lambda edge: edge.property('sessions', edge.value('session') + n_sessions)
)
```

instead of the last row I've also tried to use:
`sideEffect{ it.property('sessions', it.value('sessions') + n_sessions) }`
and
`sideEffect{ __.property('sessions', __.value('sessions') + n_sessions) }`
but it didn't help

It fails with `error message : token recognition error at: '+ '`

Comment: Gremlin does not have a `+` operator. You likely will want to use `math` or `sum`. Amazon Neptune also does not support lambdas in Gremlin.

Comment: I've already tried to use
.sideEffect{__.property('sessions', __.value('sessions').math('__ + n_sessions'))}

Comment: I will try to work up some examples using both `sum` and `math`. Note that the `math` syntax will be something like`.values('sessions').math('_ + n_sessions')`

Comment: @KelvinLawrence, 
`.property('sessions', __.values('sessions').math('__ + nsessions'))` 
fails with 
`The variable __ for math() step must resolve to a Number - it is instead of type null with value null`

Comment: I added an example using a test graph as an answer below. We can iterate using comments as needed.

Answer (score 1):

By way of a simple example, if you had a test graph created using these steps:

```java
g.addV('test').property(id,'T1').as('a').
  addV('test').property(id,'T2').as('b').
  addE('route').from('a').to('b').property('session',1)
```

then incrementing the property could be done using `union` and `sum` as follows:

```java
g.V('T1').outE().
          property('session',union(values('session'),constant(1)).sum()).
          valueMap(true)
```

which yields

```java
{<T.id: 1>: '9ec493fd-b919-ca53-a364-daf05f9cbd2e', <T.label: 4>: 'route', 'session': 2}
```

I tend to prefer `sum` over `math` purely because it lets us work with integer values. The `math` step always generates results that are floats. That said, using math we can do the following:

```java
g.V('T1').outE().
          property('session',values('session').math('_ + 1')).
          valueMap(true)
```

which now gives us

```java
{<T.id: 1>: '9ec493fd-b919-ca53-a364-daf05f9cbd2e', <T.label: 4>: 'route', 'session': 3.0}
```

To use a value from elsewhere in the query, rather than a `constant` step, we might do:

```java
g.inject(10).as('increment').
  V('T1').outE().
          property('session',union(values('session'), select('increment')).sum()).
          valueMap(true)
```

which yields

```java
{<T.id: 1>: '9ec493fd-b919-ca53-a364-daf05f9cbd2e', <T.label: 4>: 'route', 'session': 13.0}
```